# Key Lookup and Full-text index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, index

I have the following query:

```
SELECT T2.Title 
FROM TitleTable T1
    INNER JOIN TitleTable T2 ON T2.FKID1 = T1.FKID1
WHERE T1.FKID2 = @ID_PARAM1 
    AND T2.FKID2 = @ID_PARAM2 
    AND CONTAINS(T1.Title, '"' + @SINGLE_WORD_PARAM +'"')
```

`Title` is of type `NVARCHAR(100)`. All the `ID`s are `INT`.

My Execution Plan is such that it is using the Key Lookup (Clustered) operation 80+% of the time:

- Predicate: TitleTable.FKID2 AS T2.FKID2 = @ID_PARAM2
- Object: TitleTable T2
- Output list: TitleTable.Title

Each and every mentioned column is in its own non-clustered index, Title is additionally in the full-text index and there's a clustered index on the primary key as well. Is there a way to include the full-text index in the covering index or something?

EDIT: 
[image: execution plan]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key lookup operations can be avoided by the use of a covering index.  Full-text-indexes cannot be "included" in a covering index, however, including the `TitleTable` in the covering index is still useful since SQL Server can find all the details it needs for the query, aside from the full-text-query *results*, by seeking the covering index.

I've created a simple test-bed to show this in action.

First, we'll create an empty database for our test, since we [cannot create full-text catalogs in tempdb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-fulltext-catalog-transact-sql):

```
USE master;
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.databases d WHERE d.name = N'FullTextTest') 
BEGIN
    ALTER DATABASE FullTextTest SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
    DROP DATABASE FullTextTest;
END
CREATE DATABASE FullTextTest;
ALTER DATABASE FullTextTest SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
BACKUP DATABASE FullTextTest TO DISK = 'NUL:';
GO
```

Here, we'll create a mock-up of your table.  You say in the question that all mentioned columns have an associated non-clustered index, so we'll define those too:

```
USE FullTextTest;
GO

CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG ftc
WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = OFF
AS DEFAULT
AUTHORIZATION dbo;

CREATE TABLE dbo.TitleTable
(
    PK_ID int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_TitleTable
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
        IDENTITY(1,1)
    , FKID1 int NOT NULL
    , FKID2 int NOT NULL
    , Title nvarchar(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_TitleTable_FKID1
ON dbo.TitleTable (FKID1);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_TitleTable_FKID2
ON dbo.TitleTable (FKID2);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_TitleTable_Title
ON dbo.TitleTable (Title);
```

Here's the full-text index:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON dbo.TitleTable(Title) 
KEY INDEX PK_TitleTable 
ON ftc 
WITH (CHANGE_TRACKING = AUTO, STOPLIST SYSTEM);
```

I've got a database with around 47,000 words in it which I'll use to fill the `dbo.TitleTable` table:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TitleTable (FKID1, FKID2, Title)
SELECT wl.WordRow, wl.WordRow, wl.Word
FROM WordsDB.dbo.WordList wl;
```

Here's the query from your question:

```
DECLARE @ID_PARAM1 int;
DECLARE @ID_PARAM2 int;
DECLARE @SINGLE_WORD_PARAM nvarchar(100);
SET @ID_PARAM1 = 46777;
SET @ID_PARAM2 = 46777
SET @SINGLE_WORD_PARAM = N'"' + 'it' + N'"';
SELECT T2.Title 
FROM TitleTable T1
    INNER JOIN TitleTable T2 ON T2.FKID1 = T1.FKID1
WHERE T1.FKID2 = @ID_PARAM1 
    AND T2.FKID2 = @ID_PARAM2 
    AND CONTAINS(T1.Title, @SINGLE_WORD_PARAM);
```

At this point, if we run the query, we see the following plan:

[image]

As expected, there is an index seek on the `IX_TitleTable_FKID2` non-clustered index, with an associated key-lookup against the table itself for the `Title` column.

If we add a compound index on both `FKID2` and `FKID1`, we'd expect a different plan, which is what we get:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_TitleTable_FTS_Cover_NoInclude
ON dbo.TitleTable (FKID2, FKID1);
```

[image]

However, the key lookup for the `Title` column is still there.  What if we add an `INCLUDE` clause to our index above?

```
CREATE INDEX IX_TitleTable_FTS_Cover
ON dbo.TitleTable (FKID2, FKID1)
INCLUDE (Title);
```

[image]

Success!  No key-lookup operation required.  The cost of the query has also dropped from 0.016 to 0.013, so that's a win.